# What algorithm do I use to resolve the compilation order for a given set of files?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to implement a small problem to understand better in my compilers class. This is the problem as follows: Assume, I have a bunch of files to compile as follows:

a depends on nothing
b depends on c
c depends on f
d dependes on a
e depends on b
f depends on nothing

So in this case the compilation order for the files to be successfully compiled is **a,f,c,b,d,e**. I want to write my own algorithm to output the desired dependency just as an exercise. I know the linker does it automatically in C++ etc, but this is just a personal exercise. How can I go about solving this problem. Any references to algorithms/readings is much appreciated, since I'm fairly new.

Comment: It all depends on what "depends on" means, but if it's "uses code defined in", which is how robust code is written, then it makes no difference what order you compile them in. The linker sorts out those dependencies.

Comment: @PeteBecker that would be an OK answer for someone just trying to get stuff to compile.  But he said he's taking a compiler class, so I think he wants to know _how_ the compiler or linker would sort things out.

Comment: A better model of a code diagram might distinguish structural dependence and functional dependence. The former means to define a class, we need blah blah blah, and the latter means to define the implementation of class functions, we need blah blah blah.

Comment: @ajb -- in C++ there is no required compilation order, and topological sorting of source files is irrelevant. If a compiler course is teaching something else it's wrong.

Comment: @PeteBecker This is just a problem I'm trying to solve as an algorithms exercise to better understand how the linker might work on the inside.

Comment: @PeteBecker I have removed the wrongfully used C++ tag. I would appreciate if you can undo the down vote because this is a legitimate question I have in mind.

Comment: @PeteBecker 1. That's not a reason to close the question or downvote it. 2. The question is also tagged [tag:java], and a Java compiler is supposed to implement such a feature. 3. I've taken more than one compiler course and I wouldn't have considered the issue out of place in either of them. 4. Whoever voted to close as 'too broad' simply does not know what he is talking about.

Comment: @EJP - I didn't suggest closing the question, nor did I downvote it. I responded to what I see as a non sequitur in the question. And, incidentally, Java can, and is, done with separate compilation. The compiler has no need to sort out what files depend on what others; that can be done on the fly -- just compile things as they're needed.

Comment: @PeteBecker Java compilation is not 'done with separate compilation'. It compiles dependencies. This means it has to work out which file to compile before which other file, which is exactly what the question is about, and the answer. There is no *non sequitur* in the question.

Comment: @EJP - as I said, it can do it on the fly, compiling files as their imports are encountered, without any need to work out dependencies in advance.

Comment: @PeteBecker You're guessing and then assuming your guess is correct and then criticizing the question accordingly. The technique you mention isn't the only way to do it, and there is nothing wrong with a question that asks for an optimal solution. Nothing in any of this futile discussion makes the question a *non sequitur.*

Comment: @EJP -- you've demonstrated a fair amount of skill at misreading things to support your position. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @PeteBecker In Java it does make a difference what order you compile them in. Your entire position is founded on a falsehood. If you wish to maintain that I have misread something it is incumbent on you to state what and where, rather than just assert it without evidence.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment of @ajb, a quick google search brings up the Wikipedia article for [Topological Sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). However, it seems to me that if you're going to go through the trouble of making a graph to represent the problem, there's a really easy way to do this.

First, for each file you're compiling, make a node. Then have an edge from each node to it's dependency, and have an edge to a special node for if the file requires no dependency. Once that is done, all you have to do is reverse the edges and compile in a [breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) from that special node.

If you need to worry about circular dependencies or any of that jazz, then it gets a lot more complicated, but it's still doable.

Since you're asking for literature, there is a book called Data Structures and Algorithms in C++ that goes over all kinds of data structures and algorithms (what a surprise!) including graph algorithms in chapter 13.

Comment: I've been programming in C and C++ for thirty years. I have never had to sort source files to get them to compile. Sorry to be blunt, but this is nonsense.

Comment: @PeteBecker There are languages where it does make a difference.  The OP may have simply used the wrong tags.  Or maybe they're supposed to write a compiler in C++, that compiles some other language.  We don't know just what they're covering in the OP's class, so I think you have to make some unwarranted assumptions to conclude "this is nonsense".

Comment: @ajb -- if the question isn't about C++ then it shouldn't be tagged C++. If it's about C++, as it claims to be, then there is no required order for compiling files, and recommending a topological sort is nonsense. "The OP may have simply used the wrong tags" certainly seems to be an "unwarranted assumption", not to mention an unstated one.

Comment: @PeteBecker Lots of tags are wrong on SO all the time, so I don't think that's unwarranted.  Especially since (as we've now found out) I turned out to be right.  And if this is a compiler class, it's perfectly possible they're being assigned to write a compiler in C++ for a "toy language" invented for the purpose of teaching a compiler class.

Comment: @PeteBecker It doesn't 'claim' to be about C++. It was originally tagged with both C++ and Java, and it was, and is, explicitly stated to be a class problem. Your objections are both baseless and pointless. And if you were programming in C 30 years ago you would certainly have used `nm -no *.o|tsort`, which is a topological sort for ordering `.a` files.